# uisearchBar black style like appstore

Tags: ios, customization, uisearchbar

i want like this http://savepic.ru/3302429.png

but i get - http://savepic.ru/3296285.png

how you can see all input text - black 
ofc i can fix it -

```
for (UIView * v in _searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITextField")]) {
            UITextField * t = (UITextField *)v;
            t.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
    }
```

and text be white BUT search icon and icon - "x" still black (

anybody have any ideas how i can fix it ?

Comment: I dont undestand .... I can get white input text color but icons search and clear be black ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
UITextField *searchField = [searchbar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
searchField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

OR

```
for(UIView *sub View in searchBar.subviews){
            if([subView isKindOfClass:UITextField.class]){
                [(UITextField*)subView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            }
        }
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I can get white text color but me need black icons - search and clear )

Comment: Or you think setter setTextColor better ? Ok i try ;) i think setter .textColor == setTextColor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513858/how-to-change-the-uisearchbar-to-replace-the-search-icon-inside-the-text-field-w  try this for changing the icon.

Comment: Siba Prasad Hota oh ...( thnks for link need paint some icons and set manualy (