# Changing UISearchBar icon?

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm trying to customise the `UISearchBar`in my current app without much success. What I am trying to do is this:

[image]

However the end result is this:

[image]

You see in the second image I still have the original search icon there. I have not been able to find a way to remove it all together. I thought setting a custom background image would solve it, but evidently, not.

Edit: The suggested duplicate question mentioned doesn't solve the problem. Non the provided code works in removing the icon.

Edit 2:

This is how I have added the background image, which contains the orange icon on the left

```
    [self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_bar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the image on the left of an UISearchbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245342/removing-the-image-on-the-left-of-an-uisearchbar)

Comment: I have looked at that answer already. See my edit.

Comment: How have you added your custom image? The orange magnifier.

Comment: Changed the background image - see edit. Thank you. :)

Comment: Did you try any other answers from the question I linked, because setting the `leftViewMode` of the internal `UITextField` to `UITextFieldLeftViewModeNever` worked for me. I just checked.

Comment: Yes I did. I stepped through that code and the loop executes only once. Which I find odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the answer exists [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245342/removing-the-image-on-the-left-of-an-uisearchbar), it does not work with iOS >= 7.x. The following will:

```
for (UIView *subView in self.searchedBar.subviews) {

        for (UIView *subView2 in subView.subviews) {

            if ([NSStringFromClass([subView2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UISearchBarTextField"]) {

                UITextField *searchField = (UITextField *)subView2;
                searchField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me on iOS 8+:

```
[mySearchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchBarIcon"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```